# Codeigniter Cannot save text with comma to the database

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am working in codeigniter.

```
 function create($data){
    $this->db->insert(TBL_QUES, $data); 
    if($this->db->insert_id())
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

this is one of the function in my model. This is used to create/insert a record into database. But i can't able to insert the text with comma to the database. I can't able to find the error in this code.

Example Working Text: this is a string 1;

Example Not Working Text: this is a string 1, this is a string 2;

Am i have to escape the input?

I set the global filtering value equal to true.

Thanks to all

Comment: all comma separated value are identifying as a new column value. is it your requirement to insert comma separated value in DB?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understood your point. But i want to insert a text with comma. How to do that? can you guide me please..

Comment: How to i insert a text "this is a string 1, this is a string 2"?

Comment: yes I can help you.give me some moment.

Comment: will u kindly provide $data value?

Comment: Hey sorry this is my fault. I found the problem now. I am uploading a CSV file and saving the records to the database. Now the problem is I can't read the data which contain comma...

Comment: $data["columnname"]="I am here,you are there";$data["columnname"]="I am here"; may try this one. but giving you the best solution

Comment: yeah you are right, just now i found my actual problem. My problem is reading the csv files..

Comment: from csv file you are saving data to db. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may take help from this code for generating sql from csv

```
csv2sql("pre_employee","ch_data.csv");
function csv2sql($table_name,$csvname)
{
$fl=fopen($csvname,r);
//if(!file_exists('a.txt'))
//{
    $flw=fopen("a.txt",'w');
//}
$sql='';
$i=2;
//echo $csvname.$data=fgetcsv($fl,1000,",");die();
while(($data=fgetcsv($fl,1000,","))!=false)
{
    $sql.="insert into ".$table_name." values('".$data[0]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."');".chr(13);
    $i++;
}
//echo $sql;
fwrite($flw,$sql);
fclose($flw);
fclose($fl);
}
```